# Overpass QL: Possibility to set "around" globally like bounding box (bbox)

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to use the Overpass Api to get information from OpenStreetMap around my current position via Get.
Using a Bounding Box it works:

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[timeout:25][out:json];(way[%22amenity%22=%22hospital%22][%22emergency%22=%22yes%22](bbox);relation[%22amenity%22=%22hospital%22][%22emergency%22=%22yes%22](bbox);way[%22amenity%22=%22fire_station%22](bbox);relation[%22amenity%22=%22fire_station%22](bbox););out%20geom;&bbox=westlimit,southlimit,eastlimit,northlimit
```

Now I have the problem that I only know the current Coordinates (latitude, longitude). And I want to query around 10'000m around this Coordinates.

I know there is around. This would be the QL for that query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  way["amenity"="hospital"]["emergency"="yes"](around:10000,latitude,longitude);
  relation["amenity"="hospital"]["emergency"="yes"](around:10000,latitude,longitude);
 way["amenity"="fire_station"](around:10000,latitude,longitude);
  relation["amenity"="fire_station"](around:10000,latitude,longitude);
);
// print results
out geom;
```

I want to use the GET Endpoint of the API
As you can see the around parameter is repeating.

Is it possible to set it globally, like the bbox above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, you cannot define "around" on a global level.

There's been an enhancement request to shorten the query a bit by having one "wr" instead of one "way" and another "relation" query. At the time of writing, this isn't available yet.

See https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/535 for more details.